# Not able to select a disk to reinstall OS in safe mode

Tags: hard-drive, high-sierra, install, startup, safe-mode

I have iMac A1418 with High Sierra on it. I had to erase entire Macintosh HD disk hoping to reinstall OS on a ‘clean’ drive.

Unfortunately I’m not able to accomplish this as when I select “Reinstall macOS” in macOS utilities window and when it comes to selecting a disk on which I want to install OS, I can’t select a disk (Macintosh HD is displayed) and I can’t press “Install” button since it is greyed out.

It looks like window is waiting for me to click on desired disk - but I’m not able to do this because mouse is not functional and don’t see how I can select disk with keyboard.

[image]

I would appreciate any suggestions

**UPD**: eventually I resolved my issue by installing High Sierra on external SDD drive and booting iMac from it - this however doesn’t answer the question raised in this post.

Comment: Did you try a wired mouse?

Comment: @Tetsujin yes, I did, but it didn’t work either.

Comment: What happens if you press the TAB key? Can you select the drive that way?

Comment: @Monomeeth no, tab key doesn't work - i.e. nothing is getting highlighted to be selected

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am currently having the exact same issue.

Comment: @BrianSalta my solution was to erase the volume, install macOS on an external drive from my MacBook, boot iMac using that external drive and then install macOS on the volume I have previously erased.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up.  I posted a question here, if you could help at all I would appreciate it.  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366805/macbook-pro-disk-utility-disk0s2-not-mounted/366811

Answer (score 2):

When the drive isn't selectable, you almost always will want to choose Disk Utility and erase that volume.

Once it's totally erased, then run a repair operation to be sure the basic structure is good. Of course, you lose all data to do this erase, so be certain your backup isn't connected and is verified.

If the installer continues to fail, then you either have:

1. Wrong disk format entirely - post what diskutil list or disk utility shows for all the specifics of the volume format (APM/GPT) and the filesystem details (HFS / APFS / which flavor of the previous or some other like ext/fat)
2. A faulty installer
3. Some faulty hardware